# In optics, does the albedo encompass the Fresnel effect?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

**Context :**

I'm a 3D "artist", I do photorealistic renders with [Blender Cycles](https://www.blender.org/features/cycles/) path tracing.
I try to understand more in deep about albedo and fresnel effect.
Even if I'm interested in science and more specifically optics, I'm really not a scientist, so I don't understand equations if no one explains it with words.

**Question :**

So the question is, does the albedo value encompass the fresnel effect or are they completely separate notion?
The invers question is of interest too, does the fresnel effect encompass the albedo?

**How I understand :**

Till now I was thinking that Albedo was the diffuse par of light and Fresnel effect the reflexion part, but perhaps it's not that simple.
Let say I have a dielectric material like plastic, let say it have an IOR of 1.6 which means a F0 (point of view perpendicular to the surface) of roughly 5% and an albedo of 0.3 (30%).
Is it right to say that the base color of my material is 0.25 (R,G,B) and on top of that there is the fresnel effect of 5% so the albedo is 0.25+0.05= 0.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Fresnel reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) gives the ratio ($R$) of the reflected power to the incident power, assuming a **monochromatic** plane wave with  a given **angle of incidence** is incident on the infinite, **smooth** interface of two media. Therefore, in general, for different wavelengths and different angles of incidence you get different values for $R$.

On the other hand, surface albedo (as defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo)) is a practical measure defined as the ratio of irradiance reflected to the irradiance received by a (not necessarily smooth<sup>1</sup>) surface, integrated over the **entire solar spectrum** and over **all possible angles** in a given period of time. 
Therefore, it takes into account the spectral and angular distribution of (solar) radiation that reaches the object's surface, and depends on the roughness of the surface too.

Therefore, Fresnel reflection formula and albedo are not separate notions. The *physics* of the problem lies in the Fresnel reflection formula and *theoretically* you can calculate albedo from there, but you need a lot more *data* in order to do so, and it would be a more difficult task in the cases where the surface roughness leads to [diffuse reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection) of light. 
(This should be the reason why albedo is usually measured rather than calculated)

<sup>1. Optically smooth, as defined [here](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Optically_smooth).</sup>

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, so it's what I thought, not so simple. In a non spectral render engine (only R,G,B treated equally by the fresnel formula), and albedo value found with no information about how they were mesure (plane surface/object like rocks...), the best I can do is to substract fresnel F0 value to albedo to determine my diffuse color, or, have you got a better advise?

Comment: @Mareck Total surface albedo is the sum of the diffuse and specular terms so your approach seems reasonable.